# Login website with two form groups using selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to devise a code that enables me to login a website https://www.change.org/login
with the help of selenium in VBA. I am accustomed to that but as for this website, I found two groups of form and I can't specify the right direction for that
When searching using CSS selector like that `.grouped-form` I found two groups. And I have tried many things but the same problem of finding two groups
I even tried using XPath:

```
.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/header/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/input").SendKeys "yyyy"
```

but got an error.

I could solve it by using:

```
.FindElementByCss("#page .login input[name='email']").SendKeys "yakh777@gmail.com"
```

But I welcome more suggestions ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `FindElementByXPath`:

  ```
  FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='login-container']//input[@name='email']").SendKeys "yakh777@gmail.com"
  ```
- `FindElementByCss`:

  ```
  FindElementByCss("div.login-container input[name='email']").SendKeys "yakh777@gmail.com"
  ```